# ios download file with data chunks delegate

Tags: ios, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, urlsession

I want to download a file from a certain url .
what I need is the data delegate ( the delegate which gives me the downloaded data) . 
I implemented the :

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
```

delegate but it doesn't get called .

my code is :

```
func download(url: URL)
{
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.downloadTask(with: url)


    task.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    print("apending ")
    self.dataaa.append(data)
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    print("here")
}
```

the two delegate functions don't get called !

Answer (score 0):

You're using the delegate methods for a data task, but you're creating a download task.  Those two task types work differently and use completely different delegate methods.

Comment: so how can I do this ?

Comment: Either use a data task (if you want the data in memory) or implement the delegate methods for download tasks.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate